# The bash script does not continue running if it contains a call to docker-compose

Tags: bash, docker, curl, docker-compose, wget

I have 2 bash scripts to install the program. online_install.sh and install.sh

online_install.sh downloads the install.sh script from the internet with curl

```
sudo curl -L https://example.com/online_install.sh  | sudo X=<something var> bash
```

and runs it, after that it should remove all the packages it downloaded

online_install.sh looks +- like this

```
curl https://example.com// --output install.sh
./install.sh
rm install.sh
```

install.sh looks +- like this

```
something_staff
docker-compose exec -T <some_container_name> <some command>
something_staff
```

The problem is that after install.sh completes in online_install.sh (Deletion does not occur) , the script does not continue to work, although install.sh completed without errors

I found the issue that this is due to the call to docker-compose
At the same time, if you download online_install.sh to your computer and run it (without curl), then everything works

So, I would like to know why this is happening and if docker-compose is to blame

Comment: It seems unusual to me that you're running `docker-compose exec` in a script at all.  What are you trying to do with this, and can you change your image's setup so that the container initializes itself?

Comment: Yes, I did that by removing all docker-compose exec calls in the bash script, but I'm wondering why it happens that's why I asked this question :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in this way, maybe not the best option, but I could not find others

```
sudo curl -s <exmaple.com> > install.sh && sudo X=<val> bash install.sh  && sudo rm install.sh
```